# Where can I host my ASP.Net opensource project demo for free?

Tags: asp.net, hosting, project, demo

I'm developing the following opensource project and need a place to host a demo.

https://github.com/harindaka/ASPTokenInput

Is there any hosting provider which supports hosting opensource asp.net project demos for free. Having ads is not a problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of free hosting sites around, but they all have limitaitons.  If your site works within those limitations, then you should be fine.

As an example

http://www.aspspider.com/

Comment: Thanks. Created an account with aspspider.